# Scripted Python Install for Latest Version

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a scripted download/install of the latest version of python.

For Golang I can use the following URL to determine the newest version of Golang.
`https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text` and then download it.

Is there a similar URL or some other way to get the `latest` version of Python3?

I do not want to hardcode the version number... my script should simply install/update the Python3 installation in the target directory.

Comment: Interesting question, though I'm not sure how on-topic it is. Anyhow, I don't think there's an official way to do that. Perhaps you can scrape the official website ([this](https://www.python.org/downloads/) page has a table where the latest version is in the first row) or [wikipedia Python article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) which contains a "stable release"

Answer (score -1):

Hi you could use `https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-x`

and then enter the python Version you want without the dots.
For Python 3.8.10 the link would look like this:
`https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/`

Comment: OP wants to dynamically **check** what *is* the latest version, they don't already know it, and as they specifically write, `"I do not want to hardcode the version number"`